# Bigquery - Sum Product of multiple value within two columns

Tags: google-bigquery, multiplication, sumproduct

I have this value

[image: data sample]
I want to calculate a new column, which will add the product of multiplication from ticket_units_count and price, so it must be:
5 * 33104.0 + 4 * 23449.0 = 259316

How to do that in bigquery?
I tried this one

```
SELECT 
SUM(CAST(price AS FLOAT64) * CAST(ticket_units_count AS INT64))
FROM table
```

But it shows this error: Bad double value: 33104.0;23449.0
Need your help to specify the query to get the expected result

Comment: Please add readable sample data to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  ( select sum(cast(_count as int64) * cast(_price as float64))
    from unnest(split(ticket_units_count, ';')) _count with offset
    join unnest(split(price, ';')) _price with offset
    using (offset)
  ) as total
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: it works, please find this code for replication:
----
with

input AS(
    select "c" as id, "5;4" as ticket_units_count, "33104.0;23449;0" as price
)

select *, 
  ( select sum(cast(_count as int64) * cast(_price as float64))
    from unnest(split(ticket_units_count, ';')) _count with offset
    join unnest(split(price, ';')) _price with offset
    using (offset)
  ) as total
from input